# Integration by parts on manifold with no boundary

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, divergence-theorem

Background: If we have given some open, bounded subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n $, smooth functions $a^{ij}(x)$ on $U$ and smooth functions $u, v: U \to \mathbb{R}$, where $v$ and its derivatives vanish on the boundary of $U$, then
$$\int_U (a^{ij} u_{x_i})_{x_j} v dx = - \int _U a^{ij} u_{x_i} v_{x_j} dx, $$
where the index $_{x_i}$ means differentiation with respect to $x_i$.

My goal is to convert this setting to compact manifolds with no boundary.

Given a smooth, compact $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with no boundary. We also have given (in some coordinate chart) $Q^{ij}:M \to \mathbb{R}$ smooth functions. Does it follow that for $f_1,f_2 \in C^1(M)$ we have
$$\int_M \nabla_j (\nabla _i ( Q^{ij} f_1)) f_2 dv(g) = - \int _M \nabla_i(Q^{ij} f_1) (\nabla_j f_2)  dv(g)?$$ If so, how could I prove it? My attempt at proving was to bring both integrals over to one side and use the product rule for the covariant derivative, i.e. use that
$$\nabla_j (\nabla_i(Q^{ij} f_1) f_2) = \nabla_j (\nabla_i(Q^{ij} f_1)) f_2 + \nabla_i(Q^{ij} f_1) \nabla_j(f_2).$$
However I'm not sure whether that's actually valid in this case and neither do I know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean. It probably should be $\nabla _i Q^i f_1$ in that case. Should I edit the original post?
The $Q^i$ behaves contravariant under change of coordiantes while the $\nabla_i f$ behaves covariant. Though if we now put the $Q^i$ inside of the covariant derivative, I don't know whether that still makes sense...
I've been trying to derive a formula for integration by parts like this, though my knowledge in the field is rather limited...